# SP2013 - library settings won't let me edit certain columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, column, library

I have FULL CONTROL perms on a library that I'm working on.  However, when I go to the settings, some of the columns won't let me click on them to make changes or delete them.

Here are some of things worth noting:

- When I open the library in SPD and click on EDIT COLUMNS, I can only see the columns that I'm able to click on in the site;  The other columns don't even show up here.
- The columns seem to be single or multi line TEXT fields.

What do I need to do in order to change this?

Comment: What kind of columns are having this issue?  Are they apart of a content type?

Comment: All columns are part of the same content type.  I'm able to change a few of them, but not all of them.

Comment: I will say that they are all text columns (some are single line, some are multiple line)

Comment: Which content type do these columns belong to? Original content type or custom content type?

Comment: All of these belong to a custom content type

Comment: Here's something else I found - When I open the library in SPD, and look at the columns, I only see the columns I'm able to edit.  The rest of the columns don't show up.

Comment: Which is the parent content type of this custom content type?

Comment: The content type is called "Form".  The parent is also called Form.  In the content type settings, you can click on the Parent name, and you get a list of 4 of the columns (three of which are clickable).  From here, it seems that the parent type is called Document, containing the same columns.  Document's parent type is Item,

Comment: Whether the unclickable column is "Name" column?

Comment: @EmilyDu-MSFT , I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you're asking.  Can you rephrase the question?  While the library doesn't have a "name" column, it does have columns for "Requestor Name" and "Title of Request" - both of which are unclickable.